# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'languages'

Tags: python-3.x

Goal : 1.Select PDF  2.OCR PDF  3.Write tabels to excel with onefile .exe

Script is working in Pycharm perfect but after compiling to exe i am getting this traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "OCR_Menu.py", line 26, in <module>
  File "ocrmypdf\api.py", line 340, in ocr
  File "ocrmypdf\_validation.py", line 240, in check_options
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'languages'
[11220] Failed to execute script 'OCR_Menu' due to unhandled exception!
```

Any help to get this script working as a single executable file will be very appreciated!
Thank you!

```
import ocrmypdf
import camelot
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename


Tk().withdraw() # we don't want a full GUI, so keep the root window from appearing
filename = askopenfilename() # show an "Open" dialog box and return the path to the selected file
print(filename)

# if filename is not None:
if __name__ == '__main__':  # To ensure correct behavior on Windows and macOS
    ocrmypdf.ocr (filename, 'output.pdf', deskew=True,)

file = "output.pdf"
tables = camelot.read_pdf(file, pages = "1-end", flavor='stream')
print(tables.n)
tables=camelot.read_pdf(file, pages='1-end', flavor='stream')
tables.export(filename + ".xlsx", f='excel')
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're currently using `googletrans==3.0.0`, please switch to `googletrans==3.1.0a0` for the temporary fix.

Comment: Hi Mohammad, thanks, no idea where to do the switch  I installed OCRmypdf via PIP.

Comment: Check the link: https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/#history

Comment: I saw no uninstalling of 'googletrans==3.0.0' when installing  'googletrans==3.1.0a0', same traceback after running exe.